# How to make a Test Double for the RequestHandlerInterface class in Zend Expressive using Prophesy?

Tags: unit-testing, mezzio, prophecy

I'm trying to make a unit test for the `process()` method of a middleware in a Zend Expressive application. To do this, I need to mock the out the `$delegate` parameter for the method which is of type `RequestHandlerInterface` and will have the method `handle()`.

This should be pretty easy to do as I've mocked successfully with Prophesy on other objects in this test:

Whenever the `handle()` method gets called, I receive the following error: `"Unexpected method call on Double\RequestHandlerInterface\P18:\n  - handle(\n        Double\ServerRequestInterface\P17:000000004a01de0d000000000617c05e Object (\n            'objectProphecy' => Prophecy\Prophecy\ObjectProphecy Object (*Prophecy*)\n        )\n    )\nexpected calls were:\n  - handle(\n\n    )"`

Here's the test. Note that other mocks are working as expected but the `handle()` method on the `$mockDelegate` still throws the error when it is called:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function 
testReturnsRedirectResponseForHandlerWhenNoErrorsFoundRequestTypePOST()
{

    $renderer = $this->prophesize(TemplateRendererInterface::class);
    $renderer
        ->render('app::contract-form-page', [])
        ->willReturn('');

    $validateSubmitAction = new ValidateSubmitAction(
        $this->router->reveal(),
        $renderer->reveal(),
        get_class($this->container->reveal()),
        $this->logger->reveal()
    );

    $mockRequest = $this->prophesize(ServerRequestInterface::class);
    $mockRequest->getMethod()->willReturn('POST');
    $mockRequest->getBody()->willReturn(
    //create fake object with getContents method
        new class {
            public function getContents(){ return 'location-number=testLoc&contract-number=1234';}
        });

    $mockDelegate = $this->prophesize(RequestHandlerInterface::class);
    $mockDelegate->handle()->willReturn('');

    $response = $validateSubmitAction->process(
        $mockRequest->reveal(),
        $mockDelegate->reveal()
    );

    $this->assertInstanceOf(ValidateSubmitAction::class, $validateSubmitAction);
}
```

Here's the method it is trying to test. The error seems to occur when the method is supposed to delegate the request down the pipeline. See here:

```
public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $delegate): ResponseInterface
{
    ...
    // Delegate on to the handler
    return $delegate->handle($request); //<-- this is where the error occurs in the unit test
```

How can I accurately mock the `RequestHandlerInterface handle()` method with Prophesy so as to achieve an error-free test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this: `$mockDelegate->handle()->willReturn('');`, but it should be something like this this:

`$handler->handle(Argument::that([$mockRequest, 'reveal']))->willReturn('');`

In your code you expect handle() to be called without any arguments. But it's called with an instance of the mocked request interface.

Have a look at an example from [zend-expressive-session](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-expressive-session/blob/master/test/SessionMiddlewareTest.php):

```
public function testMiddlewareCreatesLazySessionAndPassesItToDelegateAndPersistsSessionInResponse()
{
    $request = $this->prophesize(ServerRequestInterface::class);
    $request
        ->withAttribute(SessionMiddleware::SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, Argument::type(LazySession::class))
        ->will([$request, 'reveal']);

    $response = $this->prophesize(ResponseInterface::class);

    $handler = $this->prophesize(RequestHandlerInterface::class);
    $handler->handle(Argument::that([$request, 'reveal']))->will([$response, 'reveal']);

    $persistence = $this->prophesize(SessionPersistenceInterface::class);
    $persistence
        ->persistSession(
            Argument::that(function ($session) use ($persistence, $request) {
                $this->assertInstanceOf(LazySession::class, $session);
                $this->assertAttributeSame($persistence->reveal(), 'persistence', $session);
                $this->assertAttributeSame($request->reveal(), 'request', $session);
                return $session;
            }),
            Argument::that([$response, 'reveal'])
        )
        ->will([$response, 'reveal']);

    $middleware = new SessionMiddleware($persistence->reveal());
    $this->assertSame($response->reveal(), $middleware->process($request->reveal(), $handler->reveal()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That was indeed the problem!